# Spring boot and XSLT: How to avoud reload xslt template each time

Tags: xml, spring-boot, xslt

We're using this code in order to apply xslt to our received http response. I mean, each time we're receiveing a reaquest, this code is:

- loading `xlstInputStream`.
- Creating a new `TransformerFactory`.
- loading a new `Transformer`.

```java
public String transform(InputStream response, String xslt) {
    try {
        InputStream xsltInputStream = this.resourceLoader.getResource(xslt).getInputStream();
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

        Templates template = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(xsltInputStream));
        Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer();

        Source source = new StreamSource(response);
        StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();

        Result result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
        xformer.transform(source, result);
        StringBuffer sb = outWriter.getBuffer();
        String transformedResponse = sb.toString();
        return transformedResponse;
    } catch (IOException | TransformerException e) {
        throw new VisorDataAccessException(e, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I think this is penalizing a lot...

Any ideas about how to reclycle all these objects? Could I use one of them as singleton?

We're using a spring boot service. I thought about creating some singleton beans...

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really as you apparenly are using different XSLT each time. So unless the XSLT is the same each time there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Not always is different. I mean, I've a limited number of `xslt`s which are located in `_/src/resources`. So, I know which are my `xslt`s.

Comment: I mean, I don't receive the `xslt` within the http request.

Comment: I don't know Spring but in terms of the JAXP XSLT API you should be able to create the `Templates` object only once and cache it as it is thread-safe and then in each request you only need to use `newTransformer()` which should be cheaper than creating the `Templates` and the `Transform` with each request.

Comment: Also you shouldn't reuse a `Transformer` as it isn't thread-safe (the `Templates` and `TransformerFactory` are thread-safe after construction).

Comment: Ánd could I reuse `Transformer`?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, no as it isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that a `Templates` object and `TransformerFactory` are thread-safe you could reuse/cache them.

When constructing your object you could create the `TransformerFactory` as a class level instance (or do this in an `@PostConstruct` method or let Spring inject it.

```java
public class YourClass {

  private final TransformerFactory factory;

  public YourClass() {
    this.factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    this.factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
    this.factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
    this.factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
  }
```

This way you have a single re-usable factory in your class.

Now you could use a `Map<String, Templates>` to cache the `Templates` object for a given xslt path and only create/load that when not available.

```java
public class YourClass {

  private final Map<String, Templates> templates = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  private Templates getTemplate(String xslt) {
    return template.computeIfAbsent(xslt, (it) -> createTemplate(it));
  }

  private Templates createTemplate(String xslt) {
        InputStream xsltInputStream = this.resourceLoader.getResource(xslt).getInputStream();
        return factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(xsltInputStream));
  }
}
```

With the above two optimizations, your code would be something like this (some more clean up as you don't need the intermediate `StringBuffer` you can directly call `toString()`.

```java
public String transform(InputStream response, String xslt) {
    try {

        Templates template = getTemplate(xslt);
        Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer();

        Source source = new StreamSource(response);
        StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();

        Result result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
        xformer.transform(source, result);
        return sb.toString();        
    } catch (IOException | TransformerException e) {
        throw new VisorDataAccessException(e, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I typed this from the top of my head, so you might need to add some catches and throws clauses here and there.